# Web page that allows you to select & run JS script via drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working web page that renders a graph whose definition statements are stored in a separate JS script. The graph is rendered using D3 and Graphviz, although I think my problem is purely JavaScript (at which I am a novice).

This is the web page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.3.1/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Graph_Test1.js"></script>

<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
</body>
<script>

var dotIndex = 0;
var graphviz = d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .transition(function () {
        return d3.transition("main")
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .delay(500)
            .duration(1500);
    })
    .logEvents(true)
    .on("initEnd", render);

function render() {
    var dotLines = dots[dotIndex];
    var dot = dotLines.join('');
    graphviz
        .renderDot(dot)
        .tweenShapes(false)
        .tweenPaths(false)
        .on("end", function () {
            dotIndex = (dotIndex + 1) % dots.length;
            render();
        });
}

var dots = [ gvFile ];

</script>
```

This is the source for Graph_test1.js:

```
gvFile = [
'digraph Test1 {',

' graph [bgcolor="dimgrey",',
'                    fontcolor="black",',
'                    color="white"];',

'"Test 1 Node 1" -> "Test 1 Node 2"',
'"Test 1 Node 2" -> "Test 1 Node 3"',
'}'
];
```

And this is the source for a different test graph Graph_test2.js:

```
gvFile = [
'digraph Test2 {',

' graph [bgcolor="lightblue",',
'                    fontcolor="white",',
'                    color="white"];',

'"Test 2 Node 1" -> "Test 2 Node 2"',
'"Test 2 Node 2" -> "Test 2 Node 3"',
'"Test 2 Node 2" -> "Test 2 Node 4"',
'}'
];
```

**Question:** I can choose which graph to render by changing the  tag that specifies `Graph_Test1.js`, or have a different page for each graph but that's clumsy. I'd like to have a drop-down that lists all possible graphs and then renders the graph I choose.

I have attempted to answer this myself and here is my (very clumsy) attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

        <select id="graph-select">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            <option value="Graph_Test1.js">Test1</option>
            <option value="Graph_Test2.js">Test2</option>
            <option value="Render">Render</option>
        </select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.3.1/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="Falcon_Graph.js"></script-->

<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
</body>
<script>

var dots;
var dotIndex = 0;
var gvFile;
var graphviz = d3.select("#graph").graphviz();
$(function() {
    $("#graph-select").change(function() {
                                            var selection = $(this).val();
                                            console.log(selection);
                                            $.getScript(selection);
                                            if (selection == 'Render') {
                                                render
                                            } else {
                                                console.log(gvFile);
                                                dots = [ gvFile ];      
                                                graphviz = d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
                                                    .transition(function() {
                                                                            return d3.transition("main")
                                                                            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                                                                            .delay(500)
                                                                            .duration(1500);
                                                                            }
                                                                )
                                                    .logEvents(true)
                                                    .on("initEnd", render);
                                            }
                                        }
                                )
            }
);

function render() {
    var dotLines = dots[dotIndex];
    var dot = dotLines.join('');
    graphviz
        .renderDot(dot)
        .tweenShapes(false)
        .tweenPaths(false)
        .on("end", function () {
            dotIndex = (dotIndex + 1) % dots.length;
            render();
        });
};

</script>
```

so my code seems very hit or miss - it can be made to render both graphs but not consistently - sometimes I select one graph from the drop down and it renders another. I think the problem is that I don't know how to make the page wait fro the `getScript` function to run and populate the `gvFile` variable before trying to render the graph, which Is why I tried to add a discrete 'render' option to the drop down to reeendeer whatever was currently in `gvFile`.

Ideally I'd also like the drop down to be populated with a list off files on the server (in 'Graphs/' for example, but I couldn't find any simple examples of doing this).

Note - the graph definitions are stored as js files that populate a var as that seemed a lot simpler that the 'ideal' solution which would be to store the graphs in their native format:

```
 digraph Test1 { 

  graph [bgcolor="dimgrey", 
                     fontcolor="black", 
                     color="white"]; 

 "Test 1 Node 1" -> "Test 1 Node 2" 
 "Test 1 Node 2" -> "Test 1 Node 3" 
 }
```

and then use JavaScript to read these definitions an populate the `dots` array.

I haven't added 'D3' or 'GraphViz' to the tags as I don't think they are really relevant to my problem.

Comment: [`getScript` takes the URL, *and a callback that runs when the script is loaded*](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). Use the callback to run what you need to.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks - I had seen the reference to a callbacks but not tried coding one yet. Very new to JS and currently I spend all my time inserting and removing brackets and braces everytime I move some code around :-)  I will look into adding a callback to invoke the 'render` function defined in the code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey As I understand it the getScript callback will run when the script had loaded, but the script (which defines the gvFile var) may not have yet run. Perhaps I could use the dropdown to simply load the script and then add a 'render' button to run it, or even add the 'render' function to the end of the script being loaded?